# What would be the recommended way to collect "global styles" into an index file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I figured I need to use `injectGlobal` more than once.

I remember reading in the docs about not using this method more than once in my app.

I have a **/globalStyles** folder which supposes to collect few different modules into one index.jsx and export 1 `injectGlobal` style in the end.

#### My Question

In my case right now I have:

1. *global.style.jsx*
2. *reset.style.jsx*

How do I export those modules so I could inject them into 1 `injectGlobal`?

I know I can save them in variables as string literal, and just add them as variables into `injectGlobal`, but then I won't have the intellisense and coloring styled-components gives.

I'm looking for the best practice if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compose the styles with Styled Component's `css` template literal, which should preserve editor intellisense:

**reset.style.jsx**

```
import {css} from 'styled-components'

export default css`
  // reset styles
`
```

**global.style.jsx**

```
import {css} from 'styled-components'

export default css`
  // global styles
`
```

**style.jsx**

```
import {injectGlobal} from 'styled-components'

import resetStyles from './reset.style'
import globalStyles from './global.style'

injectGlobal`
  ${resetStyles}
  ${globalStyles}
`
```

Basically the return value of the `css` template literal is also valid in an interpolation.  Taking a look at the TypeScript types, the things that can appear in an interpolation are:

- a string
- a number
- a falsy value (undefined, null, false)
- Styles (what `css` returns)
- a StyledComponentClass (a styled component)